# Let $d$ be a positive odd integer. Prove that there exists a positive $n \le d$ such that $d | 2^n − 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I'm stuck on this question from my textbook which doesn't even have a solution. Any ideas ?. Help would be much appreciated.
$$
d\, \left\vert\right.\, \left(2^{n} − 1\right)
$$

Comment: what about $n=\frac {d-1}2$?

Comment: @Ragnar please correct me if I'm wrong. d | 2 n − 1 means that that the "d" is supposed to be divisible by 2n-1 right ?

Comment: @kiasy Other way around.

Comment: @kiasy, no, $d|2n-1$ means that $2n-1$ is a multiple of $d$.

Comment: @Ragnar I dind't write the question correctly. It is supposed to be d | 2^(n) − 1. Can you edit plz ?

Comment: @kiasy now, the problem is a lot more interesting :)

Comment: @Ragnar I came up with a solution. d=9 and n=2 but how do I "prove" it ?

Comment: @kiasy, it is the other way around, so when $d=9$, a solution for $n$ is, for example, $n=6$, because $2^6-1=63=7\cdot 9$.

Comment: @Ragnar Ohh I see so the left side had to be divisible by the right side. If I get such question on a test, can I find a solution and just prove why it works or do I need to use a certain path to get a solution ?

Comment: @kiasy, to prove this, you have to prove such an $n$ exists for every odd $d$, for example by just ginving a formula for it. (See the answer below.)

Answer (score 5):

HINT: $d$ certainly divides itself.

**Added:** This was for the original version of the question, which had $d\mid 2n-1$.

For the corrected question, consider the $d$ numbers $2^n-1$ for $n=1,\ldots,d$. Either they are mutually incongruent mod $d$, in which case one of them is divisible by $d$, or there are $m$ and $n$ such that $1\le m<n\le d$ and

$$d\mid\left(2^n-1\right)-\left(2^m-1\right)=2^m\left(2^{n-m}-1\right)\;.$$

But $d$ is odd, so $d$ is relatively prime to $2^m$, and therefore ... ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the question has drastically changed.

Comment: @lhf: Thanks. A pity: I rather liked that hint!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Do you know about [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)?  If so, then your problem immediately follows from Euler's theorem, since $\phi(d)\leqslant d$.